# Are there identifiers for smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, public-key

Say I want to reference another smart contract in my smart contract.

Do smart contracts have an identifier (like a number 0xjdjdjdjdjjddj etc.)? And if they don't, how would you reference a particular smart contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All smart contracts have an address that can be used to identify the contract.

For example, the address for [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe1ac9eb7cddabfd9e5ca49c23bd521afcdf8be49) contract is 0xE1Ac9Eb7cDDAbfd9e5CA49c23bd521aFcDF8BE49.

Comment: Can smart contracts store and recieve funds? Do they have a built in wallet?

Comment: Yes. It sounds like you should spend some more time researching how Ethereum and smart contracts work. Check out ethereum.org for great guides!